# Is $\operatorname{Fun}^\text{small}(\operatorname{Fun}(C,\mathsf{Set}),\mathsf{Set})$ total when $C$ is small?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a small category. Then it is known that the category $\operatorname{Fun}^\text{small}(\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C,\mathsf{Set}),\mathsf{Set})$ of functors $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C,\mathsf{Set}) \to \mathsf{Set}$ which are small colimits of representable functors is cocomplete and (less obviously) complete. For instance, this is shown in [ABLR - A classification of accessible categories](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(02)00126-3), and also in [Day and Lack - Limits of small functors](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610439).

**Question:** Is this category [total](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+category)? Is it cototal?

(Totality is a property which is implied by local presentability  and which implies both completeness and cocompleteness. I am fairly certain that the category in question is not locally presentable unless $\mathcal C$ is empty, but if it were total, it would be “almost as good” as being locally presentable.)

One sufficient criterion for totality is for a category to be cocomplete, be epi-complete, and have a generator. So it would be useful to know along the way whether this category has a generator, is cowellpowered, etc.

To simpify notation, write $P(\mathcal C) = \operatorname{Fun}^\text{small}(\mathcal C^{op},Set)$ and $L(\mathcal C) = P(\mathcal C^{op})^{op}$. In these terms, the question asks, for $\mathcal C$ small, whether $P(L(\mathcal C))$ is total.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the edits. When writing the title of a question, I do consider the fact that my tex will appear in the (inessential part of the) URL that eventually gets generated, so I generally write my tex there with an eye to keeping the URL more readable. The laziness of my latex in my posts is another matter, I suppose... Maybe I'll mention that I also keep in mind that the first 200 characters of my question body will appear as a blurb for the question, and this character count includes Latex commands (though not hyperlinks). This affects how I write the beginning of my questions.

Comment: Good point.  I hadn't thought of the TeX in the title.

Comment: @LSpice It's unfortunate, I know some people feel acute pain when trying to read poorly-texed math. Perhaps I should re-balance how much weight I give to such small considerations...

Comment: Just a comment: $\mathrm{Fun}^{\text{small}}(\mathcal{E},\mathsf{Set})$ is the free cocompletion of $\mathcal{E}^{\mathrm{op}}$, for any locally small $\mathcal{E}$. So your category is the free cocompletion of the dual of the free cocompletion of the dual of $\mathcal{C}$. I think that the free cocompletion of a non-small locally small category usually has no small generator.

Comment: I would look at the example $\mathcal{C}=1$ first, which is $\mathrm{Fun}^{\mathrm{small}}(\mathsf{Set},\mathsf{Set})$. My feeling is that it is neither total nor cototal. Have you looked at this example already?

Comment: Intuitively a free cocompletion of a locally small category should have a smal generating set if and only if the original category was small… but I haven’t tried to prove this.

Comment: @Martin that example makes me wonder if it might be dependent on large cardinals (compare measurable cardinals and endofunctors without rank). Maybe not, though, if taking small presheaves gets around this

Comment: These questions are addressed in the last section of my joint paper with J. Adámek https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.02524.pdf

Comment: @JiříRosický Thanks, that's quite interesting! From your 5.1 and 5.5, $P(L(C))$ is well-powered iff it is co-well-powered iff it is concrete. From 5.4, $P(L(\ast))$ is well-powered. But I think you give enough examples to see that if $\mathcal K$ is universal, then $P(\mathcal K)$ is not well-powered, so for instance $P(L(\bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet))$ is not well-powered. By 4.3, $P(L(C))$ doesn't have a subobject classifier except when $C = \emptyset$ -- I wonder if it fails to have a cogenerator under the same conditions? Generators and totality seem to still be open.

Comment: Oh of course -- if a cocomplete pretopos has a generator, then it is a topos by Giraud's theorem. Since $P(L(C))$ is a cocomplete pretopos, it follows from Adamek and Rosicky's non-topos results that $P(L(C))$ does not have a generator unless $C = \emptyset$. So if $P(L(C))$ is total, then it is not something which can be seen by the "cheap" criterion of having a generator + being epi-complete.

Comment: Ok -- here is something close. 3.7 in [Totality of Product Completions](https://eudml.org/doc/248624) implies that since $L(C)$ is cototal, so is the free completion $Fam(L(C))$ of $L(C)$ under coproducts. Since $P(L(C))$ is just the exact completion of $Fam(L(C))$, this gives me hope that $P(L(C))$ may be _cototal_, even if totality is still murky.

Answer (score 2):

I think one can see that even when $\mathcal C = 1$, the category $P(L(1)) = Acc(Set)$ of accessible functors $Set \to Set$ is *not* total or cototal, or even compact or cocompact in the sense of Isbell. In other words, there exist continuous functors $\Phi: Acc(Set)^{op} \to Set, \Psi: Acc(Set) \to Set$ which are not representable:

**Proof** of *Non-cototality / cocompactness:*

For sufficiently large regular cardinals $\kappa$, choose some $F_\kappa \in Acc(Set)$ such that $F_\kappa(X) = 1$ for $|X|<\kappa$, but $|F_\kappa(X)| > 1$ for $|X| = \kappa$. For instance, we may take $F_\kappa(X) = X^\kappa / X^{<\kappa}$ to be the set of $\kappa$_sequences in $X$ modulo those which are eventually constant. Then let $\Phi: Acc(Set)^{op} \to Set$ be defined by $\Phi(G) = \prod_\kappa Nat(G,F_\kappa)$. This functor is well-defined because if $G$ is $\lambda$-accessible, then $Nat(G,F_\kappa) = 1$ for $\kappa \geq \lambda$, so that the indicated product is small. Moreover, as a product of continuous functors, this functor is continuous. However, this functor is not representable. If it were, then by testing with the objects $G = Hom(X,-) \in Acc(Set)$, we would see that the representing functor is $\prod_\kappa F_\kappa: Set \to Set$. But this functor is not $\lambda$-accessible for any $\lambda$, since it has as a retract the functor $\prod_{\kappa \geq \lambda} F_\kappa$, which is clearly not $\lambda$-accessible.

**Proof** of *Non-totality / compactness:*

As before, set $F_\kappa(X) = X^\kappa / X^{<\kappa}$ for each regular $\kappa$, and let $\Psi(G) = \prod_{\kappa,G(\ast)} Nat(F_\kappa,G)$ to be the large fiber product of the representables on these functors, with the fiber product taken over the functor $ev_\ast$ which evaluates at a point. Note that if $G$ is $\lambda$-accessible, then for $\kappa \geq \lambda$ we have that $G(\kappa) = \varinjlim_{\alpha < \kappa} G(\alpha) \to \varprojlim_{\alpha < \kappa} G(\alpha)$ is injective. It follows that $Nat(F_\kappa, G) \to G(\ast)$ is likewise injective for $\kappa \geq \lambda$. Therefore $\Psi(G)$ is always a small set. Moreover, as a product of representable functors, $\Psi$ is continuous. Further, the unique map $\kappa \to \ast$ induces a map $ev_\ast \to \Psi$, which is a section of the canonical map in the other direction. Using this map, we also see that for each regular $\lambda$, the representable on $F_\lambda$ (which is not $\kappa$-accessible for $\kappa < \lambda$) is a retract of $\Psi$. Thus $\Psi$ is not accessible, and therefore not corepresentable.